Long Delay from Springer Journal: Should I Continue Waiting or Seek Alternatives?
I submitted an article to a Springer journal 13 months ago. Each time I inquire about the status, I receive the same response:
"The paper is currently with the editor for evaluation and the editor will render a decision directly or will initiate the review process."
My main concerns are:
Decision Timeline: If the editor decides to render a decision without initiating the review process, is it more likely to be an acceptance or a rejection?
Review Process: If the editor does initiate the review process, how long might this take, and would it require two positive reviews for acceptance?
I am particularly worried about wasting more time as I need this article for my PhD program. Should I continue waiting or consider withdrawing my submission and seeking another journal?
Thank you for your advice and insights.

13 months seems too long. I would withdraw it from further consideration with a formal request to the editorial staff.

Is the paper such that reviewers might be especially difficult to find?
